# ¿Por que no me funciona el data annotation StringLength[] y MaxValuie[]?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp

Estoy teniendo problemas para implementar las anotaciones de asp.net mvc 5, al momento de diseñar mi modelo, coloco la anotación `[StringLength]` para validar que el usuario ingrese un mínimo y máximo de dígitos. Funciona bien, pero al momento de hacer el post nunca llego al controlador y al revisar la response aparece un error de conversión. El siguiente es la excepción.

> No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Int32' al tipo 'System.String'

Mi modelo:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 7, ErrorMessage = "mi error")]
    [Display(Name = "Rut")]
    public int UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Multiclave")]
    public int Password { get; set; }
}
```

Intente con `MaxValue[]` pero conseguí el mismo problema. Con otro tipo de error si, pero en base a la conversión de dato.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StringLength, como su nombre lo indica, funciona para datos de tipo string, y estás utilizándolo en una propiedad de tipo int.

De hecho, ¿porqué algo llamado "UserName" lo declaras de tipo int? lo mismo para Password.

Validar solo números intenta algo así:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 7, ErrorMessage = "mi error")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$")] // <-- expresión regular
    [Display(Name = "Rut")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$")]  // <-- expresión regular
    [Display(Name = "Multiclave")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Por que el username en este caso es un nombre de usuario de solo dígitos. ¿Como tendría que hacer para validar para un tipo de dato int?

Comment: Utiliza expresiones regulares, mira el código que edité-

Comment: Muchas gracias ! (:

Comment: Que bueno que te funcionó :)

Comment: Nótese que esa expresión regular no acepta ceros; igual puede utilizar el atributo `Range`: `[Range(1000000, 99999999)]`

Comment: O agregar el cero a la expresión regular.

Comment: Deberias editar la respuesta para que acepte ceros. igual la del atributo range me gusta mas.

Comment: @gbianchi pero para range tendría que cambiar la propiedad a int, y por ejemplo no podría haber un username o password así: "0000001" o así: "00100100"

Comment: Buen punto ese ultimo.